# The race has started. Are you running?

Tags: discussion, beta-progress, voting

## PCG.SE is [*going on a mission*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/lets-go-on-a-mission).

> *And so the race begins.* ***For Code Review!!*** -- [syb0rg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/27623/syb0rg) [2 days ago](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/lets-go-on-a-mission#comment4574_1137)

Let's see:

> **Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Voting & Activity**
>   [image: PCG Activity 2013-2014]
>
> <sub>[PCG.SE Voting and Activity Chart](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph)</sub>

Compare to:

> **Code Review Voting & Activity**
>   [image: CR Activity 2013-2014]
>
> <sub>[CR.SE Voting and Activity Chart](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph)</sub>

Or, as has been established before, a more comparable freshly-graduated site:

> **Web Applications Voting & Activity**
>   [image: WebApps Activity 2013-2014]
>
> <sub>[WebApps.SE Voting and Activity Chart](http://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=60#graph)</sub>

Look at the chart scales: PCG's goes up to 8K. Ours? 2K. Neither are graduated sites. WebApps' scale goes up to 800.

**Conclusion:**

Both sites are apparently headed into the right direction, but...

[image]

---

PCG's *mission* is trying to hit the same nail as we are, and that boils down to the breakdown of avid users.

I have forked @doorknob's query and made a single query that selects everything in one pass [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/174384/avid-users-rep-score-targets).

The targets have been set:

- **3** 20K users
- **10** 10K users
- **80** 3K users
- **120** 2K users

This is where we stand, as of the last SEDE update - the figures under each rep cluster represent the %target achieved, and the query only accounts for users last seen in the last 60 days:

> #### Code Review
>
> - ****20K: 133% (4/3)**** (+4) - DONE!
> - ****10K: 100% (10/10)**** (+3) - DONE!
> - 3K: 50% (40/80) - no changes on either side!
> - 2K: 48.33% (59/120) - +1 over last week, PCG 0!

> #### Code Golf
>
> - 20K: 0% (0/3)
> - 10K: 70% (7/10)
> - **3K: 61.25% (49/80)** (+9) - no changes on either side!
> - **2K: 64.17% (77/120)** (+18) - we're catching up!

### Let's beat them at their own game!

All ideas, comments and opinions are welcome.

This could also be a subject of discussion:

> #### WebApps
>
> [image: WebApps]

Comment: *hoists flags, prepares army* **CHARGE!!!!** Errr, VOTE! I mean, vote and post. actually, vote and post high quality posts and... whatever

Comment: Do you still have the link to the query? I'm curious how the number of each level user we have has changed in the last few months.

Comment: @ckuhn203 sure: http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/174384/avid-users-rep-score-targets

Comment: @Doorknob apparently CR [wins the race](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2526/23788) - sorry!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are looking for **freshly posted answers** to vote on: *look no farther*!  I have created a chat bot that automatically searches for new answers and posts them to [this chatroom feed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12723/cr-answers).

#### We have magic potion!

> [image: Asterix makes "magic potion"]
>
> *[...] Asterix eases the Britons' disappointment by claiming that he carries herbs to remake the potion, as working for Getafix has given him that knowledge. These are later revealed to be tea. With a psychological boost, the village prevails against the Romans.*
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_in_Britain</sub>

Comment: How did you write the chatbot? Mind showing the code?

Comment: @AseemBansal Yes I did, and I [put it up for review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44511/27623).

Answer (score 18):

This is just a friendly reminder to vote.  You have **40 votes** to use *every day*, and I don't see many reasons to not use them all.  **Your voting on answers is what makes the reviewing process *fun*.**

[<sub>In case you don't think I practice what I preach.</sub>](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all)

Answer (score 6):

I was curious about how things have changed in the last three months. Here's the current status compared against where we were when this was first posted.

http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/174384/avid-users-rep-score-targets

> - 20K: 166.67% (5/3) - +1 user
> - 10K: 130% (13/10) - +3 users
> - 3K: 60% (48/80) - **+8 users!**
> - 2K: 59.17% (71/120) - **+12 users!!**